# How to split a list into pages in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I connect to the API, and get a large list of items that are rendered like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Item v-for="story in stories" :key="story.data.id" :story="story"></Item>
    </div>
</template>
```

There is more 200 items in list and loading takes a time. How I can divide the list into pages of 10-20 items that will be loaded when the user goes to the page

Comment: Do you want to load 10-20 items in the start & later as user scroll down in the next batch? Also, is there image with each story which takes time to load?

Answer (score 0):

The vuetify [v-data-table component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#usage) has an automatic rows-per-page option

[image]